# Recurrent neural networks with loss of data

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, recurrent-neural-network, train

I want to train a recurrent neural network (RNN) for making predictions of some data.

I have 8 variable inputs and with them I have to make predictions of other two variables (outputs). I need RNN to capture the dynamics because past inputs continue affecting the outputs.

The problem is that I only have data 10 hours a day and the rest of the time there is a gap in my data. How could I train a RNN using data from e.g. one week?

Comment: You can't model data that you don't have. You'll need to collect the data.

Comment: I don't need to model that portion of the data, just the other one. My problem is that if I add the data from day 2 just after the data from day 1, there will be a gap in time which the neural network can't understand, as it will think that they come subsequent

Comment: That’s a sound explanation for why you need to collect that data.